# Java implementation of workflow engine

Tags: java

Homegrown workflow framework that I am working on instantiates a class for every task that needs to be called for executing a workflow. More number of tasks = More number of classes to be created. How can this be optimized? I don't want to create a class for every single task.

Eg.

```
Class MyWorkflow {
 public List < Task > getTasks() {
  return new ArrayList < Task > (
   Arrays.asList(new Task1(),
    new Task2(),
    new Task3(),
   )
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you worried about the # of classes (code)? Or are you worried about the # of instances?

Comment: I am worried about both. Tasks are generic in nature. But currently we don't group the tasks based on functionality. Eg. If we have Employee object, each operation on that object has to be a seperate task which translates to a seperate class. EmployeeCreateTask, EmployeeUpdateTask, EmployeeRetrieveTask, EmployeeDeleteTask. It would be nice if there is EmployeeCRUDTasks and each operation be a method in that class, and the framework can be modified in such a way that if the instance of the class exist, call the method else create the class and call appropriate method..

Comment: What is preventing you from creating an EmployeeCRUDTasks class?

Comment: It seems like Task should have the signature: Task(Object entity, TaskOperation operation).  where TaskOperation is an enum of supported operations.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to have one Task, or a least a few defined classes of Tasks if supporting one general task is too generic.  Varargs allow you to pass entity id, etc as required by operation.  Or pass Employee.class instead of object?

```
public class TaskRunner {

 public List <Task> getTasks() {
      return new ArrayList <Task> (
       Arrays.asList(new Task(new Employee(), TaskOperation.Delete, "10"),
        new Task(new Employee(), TaskOperation.Retrieve, "15")
       )
      );
     }
}

public enum TaskOperation {
   Create,
   Delete,
   Update,
   Retrieve;
}

public class Task implements Runnable {

private final Object entity;
private final TaskOperation operation;

public Task(Object entity, TaskOperation operation, String... args) {
    super();
    this.entity = entity;
    this.operation = operation;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    // EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = ...

    if (entity instanceof Employee) {
        switch(operation) {
        case Create:
            // Perform Create on Employee
            // Employee e = new Employee();
            // employeeDAO.create(...);
            break;
        case Delete:
            // Perform Delete on Employee
            break;
        }
        // ....
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought it might work in concept, but without understanding what you do in a particular task it was hard to know.  If you like the solution and will use it in concept, can you record it so that the question is taken off the list?  Thank you!

Comment: Here is what we do in a task: a) Each task is atomic. b) Task is supposed to be generic in nature. i.e Multiple workflow should be able to reuse the task. c) Task has different state (CONTINUE, BREAK,FAILURE, SUCCESS) d) Task participate in workflow should be able to pass the output of one task to another. e) Tasks are executed in reference to a context.

Comment: Very nice.  It seems like you can build those requirements (atomic/generic/state aware/chain the result/read a context) within a generic Task class.  Best of luck with your refactoring.

Comment: Thank you Ian. We already have that in place but each Task is a class and can perform only a single action. That is what I wanted to change and was asking for suggestions.